# phpmyadmin doesn't work after installing php5-mysqlnd

Tags: debian, php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I am currently running into some problems with phpMyAdmin. I set everything up correctly and made sure everything worked.  Then later after some developing on some pages I noticed I couldn't execute `mysqli_result::fetch_all()`.

So I did my research and found out I only had to install the package `php5-mysqlnd`. So I did (`apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`). The installation did not fail and my PHP script could execute the `mysqli_result::fetch_all()` method.

However, phpmyadmin doesn't work anymore. It simply can't connect to the MySQL server anymore (all logins fail).

***NOTE:*** every other script still has no problem connecting and logging in into the MySQL server. I also did not change any passwords. Login over the console is also possible.

I couldn't get it to work with the package installed. Then I reinstalled `php5-mysql` (which uninstalled `php5-mysqlnd`) and phpmyadmin worked again!

Not having the `mysqli_result::fetch_all()` method is not a major issue but if it is possible I would like to use it anyways. Simply because it is so convenient for debugging!

I am running a Nginx server and Debian 7.5 3.10.23 system.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you figure it out BrainStone?

Comment: No. I did not find any solutions. `mysql_result::fetch_all()` still doesn't work on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I had originally just wget'd phpmyadmin in and set it up manually.

I changed it to using apt-get install phpmyadmin. I also had issues with php5-mysql and php5-mysqlnd not being compatible versions, so I had to remove php5-mysql on all servers and add php5-mysqlnd.

The errors i was getting were From phpmyadmin only.
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
2003 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
1043 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

After installing phpmyadmin from apt-get, I basically thought "start from scratch" with configuration.

For me, it was this configuration, that was the difference between being able to login to phpmyadmin and not:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;

I removed that option and could login. No idea why!

I would suggest getting a blank template of config.inc.php and adding only the mandatory parameters and seeing what happens...